# Nested mongoose schema not works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model, nested

I have a simple application with `Nodejs` and `Mongoose`, and I'm trying to get nested results, but it doesn't work.

I have 2 models in 2 files:

I use these versions:

```
mongodb: "version": "3.1.3"
mongoose: "version": "5.2.9"
```

**users.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create user Schema & model
const userSchema = new Schema({
    IdUser:{
        type: Number
    },
    Email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email field is required']
    },
    Nick:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Nick field is required']
    },
    Password:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Password field is required']
    },
    Admin:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    Results:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'result'
    }
});

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

**results.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


// create results Schema & model
const resultSchema = new Schema({
    IdEvent:{
        type: Number
    },
    User: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'user'
    },
    Result: {
        type: Number
    }
});

const result = mongoose.model('result', resultSchema);

module.exports = result;
```

After that, I use the following query:

```
//RESULTS
//http://localhost/getEvents?IdEvent=1
router.get('/getResults',function(req,res,next){
      Result.find({IdEvent:req.query.IdEvent}).populate('User')
      .then(function(result){
            res.send(result);
        });

    });
```

On my postman, I get this result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b83cd2913769f1e267191cd",
        "IdEvent": 2,
        "IdUser": 1,
        "Result": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b83cd3013769f1e26719215",
        "IdEvent": 2,
        "IdUser": 2,
        "Result": 2
    }
]
```

I would like this result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b83cd2913769f1e267191cd",
        "IdEvent": 2,
        "User": {1, "email@email.com","Nick"}
        "Result": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b83cd3013769f1e26719215",
        "IdEvent": 2,
        "User": {2, "email@email.com","Nick"}
        "Result": 2
    }
]
```

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `populate('user')` with small 'u'

Comment: same result as ('User')

Comment: I'm sorry, it should actually be User

Comment: Here if providing you some links refer them and understand the populate function in mongoose and how to use nested query...

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7

Answer (score 0):

Here if providing you some links refer them and understand the populate function in mongoose and how to use nested query...

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7